# Отодвинуть смену пароля в Win7

Tags: windows, контроллер-домена, пароль

Дано: рабочий компьютер, введенный в домен компании. Я уехал в командировку, совершенно забыв, что как раз на это время выпадает требуемая политиками безопасности смена пароля. Находясь не в локальной сети я это сделать не могу:

```
Не удалось получить данные о конфигурации от контроллера домена. Либо он отключен, либо к нему нет доступа.
```

Остаться без рабочей машины не хочется. Есть ли варианты хотя бы сдвинуть срок смены пароля?

UPD. Зашел под VPN в доменную сетку и изменил пароль. Все нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Войти под локальным пользователем